# get bitbucket commit message for each push

Tags: python, post, push-notification, bitbucket, githooks

I want to fetch the commit message to my bitbucket repository each time a user is doing any push operation.

How can I do that?

I am in development version. So is there any way by which I can post to localhost/someurl for each commit from my repository.

Else suggest other ways by which I can achieve this.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Select the administration menu for the repository (the gear symbol), then Services. There you can set up integration with external services, such as email or twitter.

Comment: I am already doing that. I had gone through the docs, There I selected service as POST and url as http://localhost:9000/someurl, but they are saying that it will not work with localhost. then how to test it in development environment. And also I am not able to check whether the POST url is called or not. :(

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the service is run at Bitbucket servers when you push something there, so localhost doesn't make any sense. Just put your own public URL there, and you'll get a POST from Bitbucket when someone pushes your repository.

Comment: True, that is the only it seems to be. Thanks for your help pokki.